# How to add a custom CSS file in ExtJs 5?

Tags: css, extjs, extjs5

In ExtJs 4, I included a custom css like this:

```
<!-- <x-compile> -->
    <!-- <x-bootstrap> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
        <script src="ext/ext-dev.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- </x-bootstrap> -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
<!-- </x-compile> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/custom/css.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
```

The fact that the link to the CSS comes after the `<x-compile>` section makes that it is loaded later and thus rules in `custom.css` override rules in the compiled extjs theme css.

In ExtJs 5.0, this doesn't work anymore. Despite of including the custom css after the microloader, the theme css is loaded after `custom.css`:

```
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/custom/css.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
```

How to achieve that `custom.css` is loaded last in order to override some rules in the ExtJs css file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open app.json and look for the css property. Add your file in there and Sencha CMD will bundle it with the framework CSS. The default one looks like this:

```
/**
 * List of all CSS assets in the right inclusion order.
 *
 * Each item is an object with the following format:
 *
 *      {
 *          // Path to file. If the file is local this must be a relative path from
 *          // this app.json file.
 *          //
 *          "path": "path/to/stylesheet.css",   // REQUIRED
 *
 *          // Specify as true if this file is remote and should not be copied into the
 *          // build folder. Defaults to false for a local file which will be copied.
 *          //
 *          "remote": false,    // OPTIONAL
 *
 *          // If not specified, this file will only be loaded once, and cached inside
 *          // localStorage until this value is changed. You can specify:
 *          //
 *          //   - "delta" to enable over-the-air delta update for this file
 *          //   - "full" means full update will be made when this file changes
 *          //
 *          "update": ""      // OPTIONAL
 *      }
 */
"css": [
    {
        "path": "bootstrap.css",
        "bootstrap": true
    }
],
```

Comment: My app.json does not have a css property. I think this is because I upgraded from ExtJs 4.2

Comment: Thanks. This will lead me to generate a default app to compare my application to a default application.