# extjs - where to put css code?

Tags: css, extjs

I have a very basic question about using ExtJS with css.
I am trying to do some simple changes to textfields/displayfields/grids. (for example make the font size 8)
I've been reading different ways to accomplish this and it seems adding css is a good way to go.

I've found this sample to edit a grid.  My question is, where is the file that I add this code to?  I created the project in VS using NEW EXTJS6 universal app.

```
/* Grid cells when the mouse cursor is over the row */ 
.custom-grid .x-grid-row-over .x-grid-cell { 
background-color: #ff6; 
border-bottom-color: #999; 
border-bottom-style: dashed; 
border-top-color: #999; 
border-top-style: dashed; 
}
```

Comment: See: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/core_concepts/theming.html

Comment: I'm following the example, I created a theme, which does get recognized. But when I create a new file packages/local/my-classic-theme/sass/var/component.scss, -- it does not get recognized.  I noticed the sencha app watch does not refresh also when I created this file... any ideas?

Comment: I ad to change namespace to ""... no clue why though

Comment: spoke to soon.  component.scss still not be recognized in sencha app watch.  to be more clear, anything I change in sencha/packages/local/my-classic-theme/sass/var/component.scss does not get registered in sencha app watch

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be, if you don't want to create a theme override for the component, to:

- put the css file in the `resources` folder

  - you can put it basically in any folder you like, but the `resources` folder is the common place
- load the style in your `index.html` and
- add the css file to your `app.json` as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395640/how-to-add-a-custom-css-file-in-extjs-5)